# Exchange of integration and partial derivative

Tags: calculus

This is a basic question which holds true for the examples I checked. I wonder if there is a theorem/lemma which says the following:

Suppose $f(s,t)$ is a smooth function in two variables $s$, $t$ over the product interval $I\times I$.

Is the following true?
$$\frac{d}{ds}\int_I f(s,t)dt = \int_I \frac{d}{ds} f(s,t)dt$$

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer--john

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a lot of theorems about that, ranging from the Riemann integral to the Lebesgue one. See, as a starting point, [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)